# Assign value to array unless defined in perl

Tags: perl

Let have a code:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $def = 'default_value';

# this works,.
# e.g. unless here are some arguments
# assigns to element0 the value $def
my(@arr) = (@ARGV);
push @arr, $def unless @arr;
say "args: @arr";

# this also works
# same for scalar - ARGV[0]
my $a1 = $ARGV[0] // $def;
say "arg1: $a1";
```

Exists some shorten way to assign default values to the array if here no `@ARGV`?

```
#this not works
#my(@arr) = (@ARGV) // ('def');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple

```
my @arr = @ARGV ? @ARGV : ('def');
```

where you may omit the parenthesis if there is indeed just one value to assign.

That last example doesn't work because `//`, `||`, and `&&` evaluate the definedness or truth of their left-hand side, so they impose a scalar context on their left-hand side (coerceing the array into a count of its elements). See [it in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).

Answer (score 4):

> *Assign value to array unless defined*

There's no such thing as a defined or undefined array.

To assign to an array if it's *empty*,

```
@arr = 'def' if !@arr;
```

---

> *Exists some shorten way to assign default values to the array if here no `@ARGV`?*

`@ARGV` always exists.

To copy an array into another, using alternate values if the source array is *empty*, you can use the following:

```
my @arr = @ARGV ? @ARGV : 'def';
```